# when I press Button It returns error(as if not clicked)

Tags: tkinter, button, iterator, delay

This problem frequently occurs when continuing click or first click.
Is it related to **cycle** iterator??
Is it source applied as if normal checkbutton?
and I certainly use this source img button

Below is the code I copy pasted to help you answer to me
Thank you!

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import itertools as it
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1080x1000+200+50")
root.resizable(False, False)
    
class framess:
    def toggle11():
        srtchkarr[0]['image'] = next(images)
    
    def toggle12(e):
        srtchkarr[0]['image'] = next(images)
    
    def toggle21():
        srtchkarr[1]['image'] = next(images)
    
    def toggle22(e):
        srtchkarr[1]['image'] = next(images)
    
    def toggle31():
        srtchkarr[2]['image'] = next(images)
    
    def toggle32(e):
        srtchkarr[2]['image'] = next(images)
            
image_up = tk.PhotoImage(
    file='checkbuttonnormal.png')
image_down = tk.PhotoImage(
    file='checkbuttonclicked.png')
images = it.cycle([image_down, image_up])
    
startchk1 = tk.Button(root, text="startchk1", border=0, relief="flat",
                        image=image_up, command=framess.toggle11)
startchk1.config(cursor='circle')
startchk1tit = Label(root, text=" click!", anchor="w", width=5, height=2, font=(
    'aial', 18), background="#f0f0f0", border=0)
startchk1tit.config(cursor='circle')
startchk1tit.bind('<Button-1>', framess.toggle12)
startchk1.place(width=21, height=21, x=340, y=368)
startchk1tit.place(x=361, y=354)
    
startchk2 = tk.Button(root, text="startchk1", border=0, relief="flat",
                        image=image_up, command=framess.toggle21)
startchk2.config(cursor='circle')
startchk2tit = Label(root, text=" click2!", anchor="w", width=5, height=2, font=(
    'aial', 18), background="#f0f0f0", border=0)
startchk2tit.config(cursor='circle')
startchk2tit.bind('<Button-1>', framess.toggle22)
startchk2.place(width=21, height=21, x=440, y=368)
startchk2tit.place(x=461, y=354)
    
startchk3 = tk.Button(root, text="startchk1", border=0, relief="flat",
                      image=image_up, command=framess.toggle31)
startchk3.config(cursor='circle')
startchk3tit = Label(root, text=" click3!", anchor="w", width=5, height=2, font=(
    'aial', 18), background="#f0f0f0", border=0)
startchk3tit.config(cursor='circle')
startchk3tit.bind('<Button-1>', framess.toggle32)
startchk3.place(width=21, height=21, x=540, y=368)
startchk3tit.place(x=561, y=354)
srtchkarr = [startchk1, startchk2, startchk3]
root.mainloop()
```

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide the complete error message (starting from `Traceback`), [edit] it in Your question also the code You have given is not reproducible, please provide a [mre]

Comment: now updated above code have not error message but If clicking checkbutton 1 and 2 and 3 fastly or 1(first), you will find out click  problem

Comment: which part of _provide the complete error message_ was unclear? also which part of _minimal reproducible example_ was unclear? it has to be minimal. wdym You don't have the error message? if ther is no error, then there are no issues, correct? also You should write a bit more readable code and by that in this case I mean that You should use meaningful self-explanatory variable names that are somewhat different so that it is easier to read the code for example You have a variable named `srtchkarr` and `startchk1` which look very similar and therefore it is harder to read the code

Comment: thank you, I will take note of variable names

Comment: It is because you used same `cycle` iterator for toggling the 3 sets of label and button.  You need to keep *an individual state variable* for *each set of label and button* and toggle the image of the button based on the updated state.  So the *cycle* is not necessary.